# "DiscordAPIError: Guild premium subscription level too low" on Thread Creation

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to create a public thread with the library `"discord.js": "^13.1.0"` in TypeScript. I've been searching and discovered that private threads require a level of discord premium subscription, but I'm using `GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD` as the thread type, so the error shouldn't exist.

I've searched through the docs for discord API, discord.js and its guide but found nothing, here's the code for the thread creation.

```
let threadChannel : ThreadChannel = await message.channel.threads.create({
            name: `Doubt of ${nick}`,
            autoArchiveDuration: 10080,
            type: "GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD",
            startMessage: message.id,
        })
```

and here's the error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Guild premium subscription level too low
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/menitox/NeoClocker/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/menitox/NeoClocker/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async ThreadManager.create (/home/menitox/NeoClocker/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/ThreadManager.js:132:18) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/842526064827301909/messages/931311236006686851/threads',
  code: 20035,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      name: 'Doubt of Pablo Contreras',
      auto_archive_duration: 10080,
      type: 11
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you try to set the `autoArchiveDuration` to `10080`. Although you can set it to `60`, `1440`, `4320`, or `10080`,

- `4320` is only available on level 1 (when the guild has the `THREE_DAY_THREAD_ARCHIVE` feature)
- `10080` is only available on level 2 (when the guild has the `SEVEN_DAY_THREAD_ARCHIVE` feature)

If you set `autoArchiveDuration` to `60`, `1440`, or `MAX`, your code will work fine. [`MAX`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ThreadAutoArchiveDuration) is based on your guild's features.

Another thing is if you provide the `startMessage` option, the type of thread gets automatically defined and cannot be changed. The provided `type` field will be ignored, so you don't need to add it. Its default value is `GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD`.

```js
let threadChannel: ThreadChannel = await message.channel.threads.create({
  name: `Doubt of ${nick}`,
  autoArchiveDuration: 'MAX',
  startMessage: message.id,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to archive the thread after 7 days.
However, you can only automatically archive up to 24 hours if the guild has not been boosted to level 1 at least.

- Boost level 0 - 1 hour, 24 hours
- Boost level 1 - 3 days
- Boost level 2 - 7 days