# Starting thread in Discord using Pycord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I am trying to start a thread using the Pycord library. Aside from the [official documentation](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.Message.create_thread), I couldn't find any real life examples of how this goes.

So far I am running into a `Error 400 Bad Request (error code: 20035): Guild Premium subscription level too low`.

I have tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708334/discordapierror-guild-premium-subscription-level-too-low-on-thread-creation/70708766), but so far no luck.

Here is my current code, any idea of how could I approach it?

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.comments = kwargs.pop("comments")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def on_ready(self):
        channel = self.get_channel(xxx)  # Your channel ID goes here
        for comment in comments:
            # await channel.send(comment['data']['author'])
            # await channel.create_thread(comment['data']['link_title'])

            await channel.create_thread(name="wop")
```

Also, my bot seems to have the correct permissions, as seen here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

As per the error (`Guild Premium subscription level too low`), your server has not been boosted enough to use private threads, which is the default in pycord.

You can change this behaviour by modifying the `type` argument you pass to `create_thread`, as follows:

### Code

```py
from pycord.enums import ChannelType
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.comments = kwargs.pop("comments")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def on_ready(self):
        channel = self.get_channel(xxx)  # Your channel ID goes here
        for comment in comments:
            # await channel.send(comment['data']['author'])
            # await channel.create_thread(comment['data']['link_title'])

            await channel.create_thread(name="wop", type=ChannelType.public_thread)
```

Note that `ChannelType` was imported from `pycord.enums`

### References

[`ChannelType`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=channeltype#discord.ChannelType)

[`create_thread`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=channeltype#discord.TextChannel.create_thread)

https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#start-thread-without-message

> - Creating a private thread requires the server to be boosted. The guild features will indicate if that is possible for the guild.