# Discord.PY 2.0 "Guild premium subscription level too low" error when creating threads

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am simply trying to make a little test command to figure out how threads work.

I want to create a thread with the name "test" out of testing reasons.

When running the command I get an error which says:

> Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 20035): Guild premium subscription level too low

My code looks like this: (it's in a cog)

```
@commands.command()
async def crth(self, ctx):
    await ctx.channel.create_thread(name="test",message=None, type=None, auto_archive_duration=60, reason=None)
```

to clarify again, I'm using discord.py 2.0

I have tried looking through stack overflow myself and followed the answers there, but I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Starting thread in Discord using Pycord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70937404/starting-thread-in-discord-using-pycord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs, if you pass in `None` to the `message` argument, it will create a private thread, which you need Boost Level 2 on your server to create.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=create%20thread#discord.TextChannel.create_thread

You can fix that by either passing in another existing message to the `message` argument, or sending one and using that to create the thread. Keep in mind that you also have to specify the `type`, because `None` will create a private thread by default.
For the `auto_archive_duration` you can either pass in 60 or 1440 if your server does not have any boosts.

1:

```py
@commands.command()
async def crth(self, ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("whatever")
    # you could also use msg = await channel.fetch_message(some_id)
    await ctx.channel.create_thread(name="test",message=msg, type=discord.ChannelType.public_thread, auto_archive_duration=60, reason=None)
```

2:

```py
@commands.command()
async def crth(self, ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("whatever")
    # message.create_thread has no reason, message or type argument
    await msg.create_thread(name="test", auto_archive_duration=60)
```